# Ninject factory interface resolve missing constructor args from kernel

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Trying to do this with Ninject's factory extensions.

```
void Main()
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<C>().ToMethod(ctx => new C());
    kernel.Bind<IBFactory>().ToFactory();
    var a = kernel.Get<A>();
    a.Do();
}
public class A
{
    IBFactory _fact;

    public A(IBFactory factory)
    {
        _fact = factory;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        _fact.Get("blah").Dump();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(C c, string s)
    {
    }
}

public interface IBFactory
{
    B Get(string s);
}

public class C
{
}
```

The factory interface fails because it does not have a `C` to throw into the `B()` constructor. However it knows how to make a `C` from the kernel, but looking it up is beyond the scope of the default factory method implementation.

I can make a custom `IInstanceProvider` and pass that into the factory method e.g `ToFactory(() => new myCustomIIProvider())` which resolves the `C` from the kernel, but it seems like a lot of work.

Is there an easier way to get Ninject to self resolve the missing ctor arg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem isn't the binding for the `C` service, but the binding for `B`.

The default Factory instance provider will create named bindings for methods starting with `Get` (see [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface:-Referencing-Named-Bindings)).

Either change your factory method to something other than `Get` or add this to create an empty named binding for `B`:

```
kernel.Bind<B>().ToSelf().Named("");
```

Comment: HaH. Cant believe I just busted hours of trying all sorts of combinations, which I could have avoided if I didn't use the word 'Get' in my test code. Sheesh :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I've been there too. I've implemented an `UnnamedBindingInstanceProvider` without this feature since I found that I use Get a lot, but named bindings, not so much. :)